# Java Map with Threads as keys like WeakHashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local, weakhashmap

In a library, I have some `ThreadLocal` variable with some objects. I want to accumulate all these objects in one data structure and be able to iterate over them when needed. One the other hand, I don't want this data structure get polluted (additionally, this could potentially lead to memory leaks) when application scenario includes creation and death of thousands of threads. So the solution should clean data structure from objects, local to dead threads.

I think solution should be similar to `WeakHashMap` with `WeakReference<Thread>` in keys, which should additionally check if the `Thread` is not alive in the regular expunge procedure. Iteration is perfromed over `Map.values()`.

Are there are existing implementations of such data structure? Or there are some better solutions for my problem?

Comment: So, you don’t actually want to “accumulate all these objects”, but only be able to iterate over the existing objects associated with a live thread? Did I get that correctly?

Comment: @Holger I solved this here: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/223b2d43299cf94ae9095719341cf84d8f6e5106/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/impl/VanillaChronicleHash.java#L1015-L1043

Comment: That `pseudoCollectionForExpunge` is a strange hack…I mean, writing a questionable dummy class (~20 lines of code) to be able to use `removeAll` instead of writing a straight-forward loop doing the same (~3 lines of code)? By the way, if you use a [`ReferenceQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) you can directly remove the collected references without querying all existing…

Comment: @Holder haha, this is because removeAll() from array list is optimised (linear complexity), while outside loop will have quadratic

Comment: @Holger but it definitely deserves a comment in the source, thanks.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t look for the type but rather assumed that you use a `HashSet`, as you talked about thread to object associations, which implies that there is no guaranteed order anyway… As said, using a reference queue, you could remove cleared references directly, which, of course, would benefit from using a `HashSet`…

Comment: With Java 8, you could use `allContexts.removeIf(ref -> { ChainingInterface context = ref.get(); return context == null || !context.owner().isAlive(); }`, if you stick to the existing logic, and still avoid the quadratic complexity of an external loop.

Comment: @Holger I considered this.. removeIf() is implemented differently from removeAll(), it allocates bitset. On each call. RemoveAll - don't. I wanted to avoid allocations.

Comment: I doubt that you will ever notice an impact of the local bitset allocation. However, if you really care about performance, use a `HashSet` and a reference queue to avoid having to iterate over all entries in the first place. Even with the original logic, a `HashSet` can remove entries without having to shift subsequent entries…